# Ldap how to fetch user details. like email and username other details

Tags: java, ldap

I am new at LDAP calling server via java code and fetch details.

i am successfully connected to LDAP server but need to fetch details for user.

```
<login-module code="LdapExtended" flag="required">
<module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldaps://url"/>
<module-option name="searchScope" value="SUBTREE_SCOPE"/>
<module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"/>
<module-option name="roleAttributeIsDN" value="true"/>
<module-option name="bindDN" value="domai\username"/>
<module-option name="bindCredential" value="password"/>
<module-option name="baseCtxDN" value="some deatils"/>
<module-option name="baseFilter" value="(sAMAccountName={0})"/>
<module-option name="rolesCtxDN" value="some details"/>
<module-option name="roleFilter" value="(member={1})"/>
<module-option name="roleNameAttributeID" value="sAMAccountName"/>
<module-option name="roleAttributeID" value="memberOf"/>
<module-option name="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple"/>
<module-option name="parseRoleNameFromDN" value="false"/>
<module-option name="roleRecursion" value="2"/>
<module-option name="java.naming.referral" value="follow"/>
<module-option name="throwValidateError" value="true"/>
</login-module>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't retrieve attributes of the authenticated user just by adding a module-option element to the LoginModule configuration you posted.  Maybe your LoginModule implementation (you have one because you used this configuration file) has already some code in place to retrieve attributes like `cn` and `mail`.  You should be able to identify the module-option name, then.